# CSS - My div wont place in top left corner

Tags: html, css

When I'm trying to place my header-div in the top left corner, there is white space between the header-div and the top, and also to the left. How do I move my `div` to the corner?

```
body {
    width:100%;
    height:190%;
}

#header{
    display:block;
    background-color: #1B1B1B;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;    
}
```

Comment: have you try `margin:0; padding:0` ?

Comment: I think it would be better if you could paste a snap shot.

Comment: Kheema: It didn't work :/

Here you can see the space
http://i.imgur.com/xkSs14k.png

Comment: you probably need to add a "css reset" to your project. 
if you add anyway html, body, form {margin:0; padding:0} it could solve that problem

Comment: Try using `* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`

Comment: Does work [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/3A9rf/) also @Mr.Alien you may want to state what that is doing as it could cause some confusion for the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are struggling with margin and padding.

Try to add `margin` and `padding` in body.

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 190%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Here is a **[Demo.](http://jsbin.com/bojoheyi/1/)**

Comment: No, this isn't needed.

Comment: No, becuase __The problem isn't here__. The problem is that the header does not have a fixed place - the top. OOPS -- i didn't mention it. That's not your fault. Just another solution, and I thought it was another CSS reset. got enough CSS reset. Sorry, and I have un-downvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try......
CSS :

```
#header {
    width:99%;
    left:1%;
    /*I hope you don't mind that 1%*/
    right:auto;
    top:1%
    /*I hope you don't mind that 1%*/
    bottom:auto;
}
```

Try to adjust a bit when you want.
Test it. I guess it will be okay.

EDITED---

[Test Demo : Success (With Code)](http://jsbin.com/vacukoyu/7/edit)
[Test Demo : Success](http://jsbin.com/vacukoyu/7/)

Comment: what is this Jamie, it would be better to share your idea with working Demo. so anyone see the quick result.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to your code.

Use the css provided in the link and you should be fine.

Comment: And the same, this isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's more easy, just add this:

```
    body,html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#header{

    background-color: #1B1B1B;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;    
}
```

You need to add html tag, and padding & margin.

Luiggi.

Answer (score -1):

Add `margin:0;` and `padding:0;`.